# Linear Regression Model that improves as the user selects and trains data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm developing a script that detects peaks on a signal data from a biological source. I want to create a semi-automated model that helps predict which peaks are the correct ones. This script improves as the user manually selects a few of these peaks to help teach the model which ones are correct.

The workflow I'm trying to attain is this:
1. User manually selects data
2. Script obtains the correct data and fits it into the model
3. Use the model to predict the likelihood of a given peak to be correct.
4. Hopefully with enough data and training, it could be automated to run through the rest.

I also don't know the name of the general topic and I'm struggling to find what to google.

I've tried to fit it on linear regression model in scikit learn but I don't have enough datasets (as it learns from the user's first intervention). Is what I'm doing possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the general-ness of this answer but the OP asked for general topics.

It sounds like [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) and [here for scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html#semi-supervised) and [here for more details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-supervised) may work.

There is no labeled data to start. A manual process is started to gain some labeled data. Soon, semi-supervised can kick in and take over - with a process measuring its accuracy. A match to your situation and a good place to start.

Eventually you may have "enough" correctly labeled data that you can investigate fitting a classic algorithm to predict the remainder. "Enough" being relative to how hard the problem is. Could be tens, hundreds, thousands, ...

Depending on other details of your situation, [Reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) may work. As you described the situation, this may not work but there may be other details in your environment to leverage this family.

Word of warning - machine learning and semi-supervised in particular may not always work great to every problem. Measure, measure, measure.

Comment: Thank you Craig! I read through the links you sent but the methods still currently processes the outputs by batch (i think). Although it can be tweaked, I think it still would be more productive to use Online ML. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all your help. I was talking to a colleague and he referred me to [Online Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning). I think this was the one I was looking for. Although I would not be handling time-series data nor streaming data from online, the method i think is sufficient for my needs. This method allows that data is trained one by one and not as a batch. I think SciKit Learn currently does not have the ability of out-of-the-box online machine learning.

[This](https://maxhalford.github.io/slides/creme-pydata/#1) i think gives a great rundown on the strengths of online machine learning (also showcasing of the creme python library).

Thanks again!